# Multiple Frontends - Java Backend

Tags: java, php

I just started working on a project which will about making a big website.

With big i mean:

- Webshop
- Forum
- Normal Website (Information pages etc..)

At first i just wanted to pick a decent open-source webshop and just built my site around it.

But then i started thinking about how to expand etc.

I started to think how i would like this website to be acces from a mobile phone. Not just with a browser but with an App. (I have decent experience in making apps for Android & Iphone). So the real question is:

Would it be smart to make the "Core" of my whole website in Java and use services to acces it and thus allowing different frontends to use the same "Core". Like:
- PHP for browser frontend
- Java (android) for the android App
- Objective C for the IPhone App.

And let them all just communication to the "Core" through REST (Json).

What will be the advantages / disadvantages with this approach and will there be a significant delay in rendering eg. a webpage (http request to php, then php making calls to java server (different physical server) then accessing the database and then returning it all, so php can format it to HTML).

Hope hearing some answers or suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I would skip the Java layer and make the "core" PHP. There is a wealth of tools and frameworks (like Zend FW) for building thoses components in PHP. Design your application around a REST interface and allow your mobile apps to use REST.

Better yet, use Rails. It's so easy to design and set up a REST interface.

Comment: Better yet, use Django, better yet, use Catalyst … better yet *insert your favourite language and framework here*. (Which probably brings you back to Java, but ho hum)

Comment: So do lots of things. Fleeing to a different programming language isn't generally the best option. I found something claiming to be [the leading RESTful framework for Java](http://www.restlet.org/) in a few seconds with Google. A little more time invested and someone could have enough information to make a good choice.

Comment: Instead of skiping the Java layer, i prefer to skip the PHP layer. After some research i came to the conclusion , java knowledge is worth more then php knowledge. This might sounds a bit weird, but in the branch my dad works at there is a lot more work for Java programmers, than php programmers. So i think i will stick with a Java Front and Backend. Propably using JSP to making the website. Thanks for the quick answer! :D

Comment: I just had a look at RoR. And i got to admit that it looks really promising!

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is “smart”. The only changes I suggest are:
Use the same platform to build both the "core" and the "browser frontend." This way you will have more productivity.

Keep the "core" and "browser" frontend on the same server, if possible in the same process. Unless you have a reason do it differently. This will reduce problems with performance, latency and so on.

Comment: May i ask which programming language you suggest? I was looking at RoR but that kinda takes the Presentation Layer - Business Layer - Data Access Layer idea away. Cause lets say i build it all on PhP, and when it grows and i see Java would be a better fit for the bussiness layer, it would be pretty simple to just replace the layer. But i can't see how that would work in RoR. Thanks

Comment: I suggest Java, just because is my prefered language/platform. But there are another options. The decision depends of your background.

If you like Java, take a look at http://www.playframework.org/

Comment: I'am pretty sure i will stick with a Java backend, not sure which framework tho. And iam considering using GWT for my Frontend Website. I have no clue how easy/hard it will be to make an forum and/or webshop with this combo, but anything is possible ;) Thanks for advices helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

If you're already familiar with Java I would suggest you look at something like [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) (or GWT + third-party libraries like [Ext GWT](http://www.sencha.com/products/extgwt/) or [Smart GWT](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/)) for your front-end. I don't see the point in picking another language for the front-end unless you *really* want to learn something else (e.g. PHP as you suggest in your question).

I think the rest of your approach is sound (i.e. Java on the backend, providing RESTful services, etc.)